# How to export data in R to a directory that you have created with arguments from the command line?

Tags: r, command-line, directory, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying to save data (e.g. a png image) into a folder that I create from the arguments of the command line.

This is my script.

#myscript.R

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla


args<-commandArgs(TRUE)

y=sample(10)
print(args[1])

dir.create(file.path(args[1]), recursive = TRUE)

newfolder=args[1]

png("/home/user/test/newfolder/myplot.png",height=2000,width=2000,res=300)
plot(y)
dev.off()
```

When I launch it, giving 1 parameter (=the name of the directory that I want to create) ---> `./my_script.R mynewfolder` it does create the directory, but it gives me this error:

```
[1] "mynewfolder"
Error in plot.new() : 
  could not open file '/home/user/test/newfolder/myplot.png'
Calls: plot -> plot.default -> plot.new
Execution halted
```

It seems that the plot is drawn before the new folder is created, for that reason it doesn't recognise it.

I saved the `args[1]` in the variable newfolder just in case it was necessary (since I tried writing the args argument and it didn't work either)

```
 png("/home/user/test/args[1]/myplot.png",height=2000,width=2000,res=300)
    plot(y)
 dev.off()
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?
I need to create the folder first (through bash or R) depending on the user's arguments and use that folder in R to save data.

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that I wanted to paste one output with strings. I needed `paste0`.

```
 png(paste0("/home/user/test/", args[1], "/myplot.png"),height=2000,width=2000,res=300)
```